# The purpose of this screen at boot time (thinkpad t43, archlinux)

Tags: boot

I see this screen at boot time and I'm prompted to question about it given that it is displayed at every boot for a relatively long time (perhaps a minute or more). What is it's purpose and can it be done away with?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your first device in BIOS is `network/PXE`. Check your BIOS and set the hard drive as first boot device.

Comment: I didn't see this type of setting in the bios.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PXE is [Preboot Execution Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) -- the computer is trying to boot off the network, but you don't have any PXE boot servers on your network, so eventually it times out and tries to boot off the hard disk next. This doesn't actually have anything to do with Linux, it's controlled by your BIOS. Look for a section in your BIOS for controlling boot order, and make sure network is below hard disk in the list

Comment: @jhstuckey -- Why delete the question?  Might it not be useful for someone else?  (Maybe the title of the question could be made less generic so that it is easier to find..?)